# Create New Date with string in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, datetime

I have string with format:

```
Dim date As String = "2014/08/20 21:00"
```

I can't create new date with this format string

```
 Dim date2 As DateTime =DateTime.Parse(date ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Can convert string "2014/08/20 21:00" to "20/08/2014 9:00 PM" ?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? date is a keyword in .Net and isn't valid for use as an identifier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As MarkHall suggested, do avoid using any keyword as an identifier.

and if your dateString is always in the format of `yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm`

Try below:

```
Dim dateString As String = "2014/08/20 03:00"
Dim formattedDate As String = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt")
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

```
Dim date As DateTime = "2014/08/20 21:00"
Dim date2 as Datetime = format(date,"yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm tt")
```

Comment: The result would be `20/08/2014 09:00 PM` instead of `20/08/2014 9:00 PM`. and the date and month might just mixed up in some case.

Answer (score -1):

Specify the format on the ToString parameter

```
 Dim dtStr As String = Convert.ToDateTime("2014/08/20 21:00").ToString("dd/MM/yyyy h:mm tt")
           'Output
           '20/08/2014 9:00 PM
```

Comment: Can you pls enlighten me why my answer is  -1? thanks

Comment: the date and month might just mixed up in some case